# Trying to wire for Ecobee thermostat

Tags: wiring, thermostat, thermostat-c-wire

I have an ecobee thermostat I'm trying to hook up, but I can't figure the wiring out. We have fuel-oil boiler and an AC, with the oil boiler using radiant water pipes (as well as heating our water for the tap) and the AC hooked up to a regular HVAC type of whole house fan. There is no c wire, so I was trying to, on the AC HVAC fan, jump G to Y and then hook the old G wire up to C. But when I looked at the house fan, I saw this:
[image: HVAC fan wiring]

Am I not looking in the right place, or is there something non-standard going on here? For reference, this is the wiring for the thermostat:

[image: Thermostat wiring]

The wiring for the thermostat is G, W, Y, R, and Rc with no C (and the thermostat doesn't work if you take out the batteries, so I know the C wire isn't there). What should I be doing, here? Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the wiring diagram for your air handler/furnace please?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that. Where do I find the wiring diagram, or is that something I generate?

Comment: Often the wiring diagram will be somewhere on or in the unit. Open access panels and look for it, or find the exact model number and look online.

Comment: @PhyPa -- it should be posted on an access panel -- if you can't find it, at least get us the make/model so we can try to search online for it